# HTML5 pushstate on angular.js, link to download the file is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, pushstate

> Today i am trying to use HTML5 pushstate in my application to remove #
>   from
>       url. To achieve this I have injected $locationProvider in router and 
>       and doing this $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); as i have found from 
>       so many online resources. Initially it was not working then i removed 
>       all the # from urls and added  in index.html.
>
> ```
> Tts working fine for every url in whole application.
> In my application u can upload file and if file uploaded successfully,
> File name would be visible as a on the page and if u click on the
> file name you would be able to download it.
>
> MY PROBLEM is now in pushstate, if we click on file name nothing is 
> happening. I tried multiple combination but no luck.
> ```

```js
// Router.js
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'mainCtrl'
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

```html
<!--here is the link which is not working-->
<!--{{documentUrl}} stands for /api/document/getExistingFile -->
<tr data-ng-repeat="fileModel in files">
        <td>
            <span ng-show="fileModel.status == '200'">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-href="{{documentUrl}}/{{fileModel.id}}">{{fileModel.file.name}}</a>
            </span>
            <span ng-hide="fileModel.status == '200'">
              <strong>{{ fileModel.file.name }}</strong>
            </span>
        </td>
  
  <!--below code of index,html where i am defining <base href="/"> -->
  
  <head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

Comment: Update: When I right clicked on the file name and selected the option "open the link in new tab" then i am able to download the file. Is there any alternate to achive this?